# SharePoint - Using a Content Query Webpart across site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

This is quite a simple question to ask, hopefully the answer is as straight forward! Can you use a Content Query Webpart on Site Collection A to read data from Site Collection B?

If it's not supports right out of the box, are there some configuration options which you can use to make it happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No configuration option will enable you to have a cross site content query webpart.

You can either create a custom web part that will do it or buy one (several options out there, [here is one](https://web.archive.org/web/20120413182712/http://www.lightningtools.com:80/lightning-conductor-2010-web-part.aspx)

If you decide to create your own web part, you will easily find code online that will help you. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ramg/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart).

Comment: Fair enough, that's rather what I suspected! Unfortunately I need the styling functionality the CQWP provides via the ItemStyle.xsl so I think I'm just going to tell the client it can't be done :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it must be within the same site collection as it uses the SPSiteData query, which works within the site collection